# Swiper navigation by pages instead of items

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

By default, if multiple slides visible, swiper navigation next/prev buttons navigate to next slide, and pagination bullets quantity is equal to slides quantity.

If there are some way to navigate to next/prev page by buttons and make pagination bullets quantity equals to pages quantity instead of items quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set slidesPerGroup parameter equal to slidesPerView parameter

```
slidesPerGroup: 3
```

and, if you had different items by screen width, then, for example

```
breakpoints: {
    1200: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slidesPerGroup: 3
    },
    1700: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        slidesPerGroup: 4
    }
}
```